# Proof regarding the existence of elements such that their product is an element of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to prove that for $A,B \trianglelefteq G$, $D \leq G$, any $x \in G$ satisfying $\exists c \in G, a \in A: ca \in B \land xc \in D$ also satisfies $\exists d \in D, b \in B: xdb \in A$. I was able to prove it by considering sets $C(X,Y) := \{x \in G\;|\;\exists y \in X: xy \in Y\}$, but the proof is rather long. Is there a short proof for that statement?

Answer (score 1):

Let $c \in G$ and $a \in A$ be such that $ca \in B$ and $xc \in D$.

Define $d = (xc)^{-1} \in D$ and $b = x(ca)x^{-1} \in B$ (by normality of $B$). Then
$$xdb = x(xc)^{-1}x(ca)x^{-1} = xc^{-1}x^{-1}xcax^{-1} = xax^{-1} \in A$$
by normality of $A$.

Some insight into the thought process here:

- You need an element $d \in D$. You know that $xc \in D$, and since $D$ is just a plain old subgroup, the only nontrivial elements of $D$ accessible to you are $xc$ and $(xc)^{-1}$. This suggests either $d = xc$ or $d = (xc)^{-1}$. Since $d=xc$ would give you an $x^2$ term in $xdb$, it is more likely to be $(xc)^{-1}$.
- You need an element $b \in B$. So far we have $xd = x(xc)^{-1} = xcx^{-1}$, so to cancel the $x^{-1}$ we need $b = x \cdot (\text{something})$. Since $ca \in B$ and $B$ is normal, we have $x(ca)x^{-1} \in B$, so this is a good candidate for $b$.

Then multiplying everything together, it works out!